# NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'object detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

i am trying to get the absolute url ... and having an error.

this is my models.py

```
class News(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    text = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('object detail', {}, {
            'slug': self.slug,
            'year': self.date.strftime('%Y'),
            'month': self.date.strftime('%b'),
            'day': self.date.strftime('%d')
        })

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "News"
        ordering = ('-date',)
```

and this is my urls.py

```
dictionary = {
    'queryset': News.objects.all(),
    'date_field': 'date',
}

urlpatterns= patterns(
    'django.views.generic.date_based',
    url(
        r'(?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3})/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[-w]+)/$',
        'object_detail',
        dict(dictionary, slug_field = 'slug', template_name = 'cms/news/object.html'),
        name='object detail'
    ),
)
```

when i do this is django shell

```
>> from cms.models import News
>> all = News.objects.all()
>> for single in all:
>>     single.get_absolute_url()
```

i get this following error in console.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/mouse/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 11, in _curried
    return _curried_func(*(args+moreargs), **dict(kwargs, **morekwargs))
  File "/Users/mouse/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 883, in get_absolute_url
    return settings.ABSOLUTE_URL_OVERRIDES.get('%s.%s' % (opts.app_label, opts.module_name), func)(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/mouse/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/__init__.py", line 35, in inner
    return reverse(bits[0], None, *bits[1:3])
  File "/Users/mouse/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 476, in reverse
    return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
  File "/Users/mouse/.virtualenvs/proj/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 396, in _reverse_with_prefix
    "arguments '%s' not found." % (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs))
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'object detail' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'year': '2013', 'slug': u'2013-season-details', 'day': '19', 'month': 'Feb'}' not found.
```

where and what i could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to satisfy the `year`, `month` and `day` keyword arguments in your get_absolute_url method in addition to the `slug`. I would also pass in an empty tuple instead of `None` for the positional arguments.

Comment: just updated the models.py get_absolute_url() function .. but now i have a different error.

Comment: Your regex for month doesn't match upper and lowercase characters. The month in your example is 'Feb'. Changing your regex to `\w+` should get you going. Also, change your regex for slug to: `[\w-]+`

Comment: i changed my regex to `?P<year>d{4})/(?P<month>[a-z]{3}\w+)/(?P<day>w{1,2})/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/$'` ... nothing happened

Comment: r'(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$'

Comment: thanks ... it is giving me problem on one item only now ... must be something wrong with my entry .. otherwise .. its okay.